# Ubuntu 12.10 can't shut down properly

Tags: 12.10, shutdown

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and after upgrading from 12.04 I'm no longer able to shut down my pc. The system get stuck trying to shut down and I can see the text

"acpid:exiting"

what can I do?

Comment: Does this problem occur everytime when you try to shutdown the PC?

Comment: Yes, it happens every time :(

Comment: Do you have any network filesystem mounted or any other networking service active?

Comment: I have a folder shared on my local network

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it has almost shutdown but just won't halt/poweroff (which is what anything related to `acpi` usually means), then just use the power button to halt it/power it off.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my system got stuck during the shutdown, but it didn't show the same text that you specify.
I tried modifying the grub, I used the terminal with the different commands possible to force shutdown the system and none worked, 
However I've found a solution by updating the BIOS, maybe you can try this.